# Can't Pass instance to the view LetsRate Gem Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is what my controller looks like

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @restaurant = Restaurant.find(1)
    end 

    def new 
    end 
end
```

and here is my view

```
Friendliness: <%= rating_for @restaurant, "friendliness" %>
Taste : <%= rating_for @restaurant, "taste" %>
Price : <%= rating_for @restaurant, "price" %>
```

I have gone to rails console to made multiples restaurants.

The problem is when i changed the index method in my controller to this

```
def index
  @restaurants = Restaurant.all
end
```

and changed the `@restaurant to @restaurants` in the view.

the

`<%= rating_for %>` is a helper method from the gem that allows me to create a star rating system just like what yelp has

The problem is this doesn't work? I keep on getting

```
 (undefined method `average' for nil:NilClass):
```

that means the '@restaurants' isn't initialize but it should be. 
The letsrate gem allows you to add a rating feature to your model.

Comment: I guess the gem you're referring to is https://github.com/frane/rating_for? My understanding is that it only works for a single record. `Restaurant.all` will return a collection of models, not a single resource.

Comment: @KevinSjöberg I am using this https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate

Comment: The same goes for that gem as far as I'm concerned.